# Is there an infinitely differentiable function such that $f$ intersects the $x$ axis only at the origin and no derivative of $f$ is $0$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Is there an infinitely differentiable function $f$ such that

- $f(x)=0  \iff x=0$,
- $f$ is infinitely differentiable
- No derivative of $f$ is ever equal to zero.

Comment: Think about what you can do with the exponential function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ s.t $f(x)=e^x-1$.

Comment: Precisely what I thought about when I saw the question. (+1)